# Усваиваемость или усвояемость? Как правильно?

Tags: орфография

Усваиваемость или усвояемость? Как правильно?

Comment: Вопрос родственный, но едва ли дубликат. Да и на вопрос по ссылке (о других частях речи) убедительного ответа не видно.